# Advanced Pointer convoluted syntax

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was fidgeting with the pointers thingy.graduated from pointers -> array of pointers -> function pointers -> pointer to pointers..

Here's what i am stuck at...mostly the convoluted syntax.

Lets say i have an array of integers.

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3..};
```

also i have array of pointers

```
int* ptr[4];
ptr[0] = arr;
```

here ptr[0] will point to 1
and ptr[1] will point to some other location

This works perfectly !!

Now considering above background i tried this.

```
char* crr[4] ={"C","C++","C#","F#"};
char** btr[4];
btr[0] = crr;
```

which works as pointer in oth element of btr is pointing to another pointer element in crr.

Then i tried this.

```
char* crr[4] ={"C","C++","Java","VBA"};
char** btr[4]= &crr; // Exception: cannot convert char* [4] *  to char**[4]
```

but when i do this it works :O

```
char* crr[4] ={"C","C++","Java","VBA"};
char* (*btr)[4]= &crr;
```

i have not understood the last two scenarios. The use of brackets on RHS Pls explain.

Comment: N.B. In C++, `"C"` is of type *array of 2 `const` char*, and the conversion to *pointer to char* (w/o `const`) has been removed in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you write

```
btr[0] = crr;
```

the expression `crr` has type "4-element array of `char *`"; since it is not the operand of a `sizeof` or `&` operator, it is converted to type "pointer to `char *`", or `char **`.  This matches the type of `btr[0]`.

However, when you write

```
char** btr[4]= &crr;
```

the expression `crr` is the operand of the `&` operator; thus, the type of the expression `&crr` is "pointer to 4-element array of `char *`", or `char *(*)[4]`.

The parentheses are necessary because the postfix `[]` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator; the expression `*a[i]` will always be parsed as `*(a[i])`.  Thus,

```
T *a[N];               // a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];             // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *(*a)[N];            // a is a pointer to an N-element array of pointer to T
```

The same is true for pointers and functions:

```
T *f();                // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();              // f is a pointer to a function returning T
T *(*f)();             // f is a pointer to a function returning pointer to T
```

Comment: Thanks John....that explains the bracket stufff...clear picture now...guess i have to deal with the syntax then.

Answer (score 3):

```
char** btr[4]= &crr; // Exception: cannot convert char* [4] *  to char**[4]
```

That's trying to initialise an array (of pointers to pointers) from a pointer, which you can't do. If you wanted to initialise the first element to point to `crr` (as in your first example), then you'd do

```
char** btr[4]= {crr};
```

The last example is declaring a pointer to an array (of pointers), and initialising it from a compatible pointer.

Note that your original array should be of `const char *`, not `char *`, since it contains pointers to (constant) string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your definitions:

1. Array of size 4 of char*

   `char* crr[4] ={"C","C++","Java","VBA"};`
2. Array of size 4 of char**

   `char** btr[4]`
3. Pointer to an array of size 4 of char*

   `char* (*btr)[4]`

Now you are trying to assign `Array of size 4 of char*` to `Array of size 4 of char**` and they are of different type, so you, obviously, have a error. Still there is another rule(which is dominated): you can't initialize array without curly braces, so array should be initialized with new data not to be a pointer to other array.

And you have absoulutely legal pointer type `Pointer to an array of size 4 of char*` to which your array address could be assigned